# The type software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am following the [example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/sns/src/main/java/com/example/sns/PublishTopic.java) code for publishing a topic to SNS, as seen below:

```
package aws.sns;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClientBuilder;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;

public class AWSNSPublisher
{
    SnsClient client;
    
    public AWSNSPublisher()
    {
        SnsClient sns = SnsClient.builder().region("region").build();
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse is giving me this error:

```
The type software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have the following JARs on my buildpath (I do **not** have the ability to use maven):

1. aws-sdk-java-2.17.29
2. sdk-core-2.17.29
3. sns-2.17.29

It's exhibiting some other weirdness, which I'm chalking up to the above error: The code completion suggests no other methods for `SnsClient.builder().` other than those inherited from `Object`:

[image]

I've also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project to no avail.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I need to do to make this happy. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just executed this example code -- as shown here:

[image]

As you can see, I set a break point and walked through the code which was successful. I use IntelliJ. However, for your issue in Eclipse; did you setup your environment and use the POM that is part of this Git repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/sns

It looks like your environment did not pull in all of the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

However, I do not have the ability to utilize the pom.xml as that is a maven thing, which I am not capable of utilizing.

Comment: That is your issue. If you do not use Maven or Gradle - how are you pulling in all of the dependencies required to successfully invoke AWS services?

Comment: I understand that not using either of those is the problem, but I simply cannot use them. I am manually trying to track down the JARs I need, so I just need help finding what I need to make this work.

Comment: I am looking into this for you. I am asking the SDK team for their thoughts

Comment: Look at this page to determine the dependent JARS that you need. Then you can download all the JARS using the Maven page.  https://search.maven.org/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-core/2.17.29/jar

Comment: So I've picked through some of them and gotten past the "cannot be resolved" problem. Now it's saying: The method build() is undefined for the type SnsClientBuilder. I've added several other jars from the list you've provided with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem: `The type software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` by importing this following [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-core/2.17.30).

I still had issues once that was resolved. I picked through the list of AWS jars that smac2020 provided and finally got it all happy. Here's the final list of jars:

- [aws-core-2.17.30.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-core/2.17.30)
- [regions-2.17.30.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/regions/2.17.30)
- [sdk-core.2.17.30.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/sdk-core/2.17.30)
- [sns-2.17.30.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/sns/2.17.30)
- [utils.2.17.30.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/utils/2.17.30)